# System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox and dispose

Tags: c#, windows, combobox, controls, dispose

I have a xaml defined ComboBox:

I populate this ComboBox(Name1) then do updates. I get a memory leak. From research on the web this ComboBox needs to be disposed but I can find no reference to a method for System.Windows.Control.ComboBox. Population is from db which is disposed on close.

using VS2010/2012 and c#.
I have tried using Dispose inline within the class, error message says no definition for System.Windows.Control.Combobox exists for Dispose.

code within disposecombobox never gets actioned.

I have tried using IDisposable, all to no avail. the IDisposable was applied to the class containing the update code as well as to disposecombobox.

OnselectedItemChanged is used repeatedly, but is not (I don't think) a class, which I suspect causes the error.

On button_update click update actions are performed with references to the combobox on delete or insert. However the memory error still occurs on amend which makes no reference to the combobox after onSelectedItemChanged.

I've just changed Name1.Dispose to disposecombobox.Dispose() and now get the error:
       an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or  property 'WpfApplication1.disposecombobox.Dispose()'

am I on the right lines? and if so what is wrong?

How do I go about it?

My code:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Name1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286"
 Margin="331,118,0,0" Height="30" IsDropDownOpen="True" Grid.Row="0" MaxDropDownHeight="60"
 MinHeight="5" FontSize="20" SelectionChanged ="Name1_SelectedItemChanged"
 TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Name1_TextChanged" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="False" TabIndex="1" />
```

And:

```
Name1.Dispose();
```

and

```
public class disposecombobox
{ 
    private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
    bool disposed; 
public void Dispose()
   {
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    { 
       if (!disposed) 
       { 
           if (disposing) 
           { 
              if (components != null) 
              { 
                  components.Dispose(); 
              } 
           } 
       disposed = true;
   }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. In the meantime you can provide us with some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="Name1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286" Margin="331,118,0,0" Height="30" IsDropDownOpen="True" Grid.Row="0" MaxDropDownHeight="60" MinHeight="5"  FontSize="20" SelectionChanged ="Name1_SelectedItemChanged" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="Name1_TextChanged" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="False" TabIndex="1" />

Comment: Name1.Dispose();and  public class disposecombobox 
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
        bool disposed;
      public void Dispose()
       {
          this.Dispose(true);
         GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (components != null)
                    {
                        components.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                disposed = true;

Comment: You can delete your commends and edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
use xaml code above

in codebehind
using System.ComponentModel;

define class myclass :Idisposable
{
private System.ComponentModel.Container components = null;
bool disposed;
method1
{
     code
}
method
{
     code
}

myclass newobj = new myclass();
newobj.Dispose();

public void Dispose()
{
   this.Dispose(true);
   GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
   if (!disposed)
   {
       if (disposing)
       {
           if (components != null)
           {
              components.Dispose();
           }
       }
            disposed = true;
       }
  }
  public interface IDisposable
  {
      void Dispose();
  }

  protected bool IsDisposed
  {
      get;
      private set;
  }
```

}

this seems to work